# How to receive webhooks from shoppy.gg in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, webhooks, nodejs-server

I'm trying to make a system that receives a webhook from Shoppy.gg and if that webhook is the webhook that is "order:paid", it gets the email of the person who ordered and signs that person to the service i'm making.
The only problem i'm having is that i don't know how to make shoppy.gg send webhooks when an order is completed. I checked their docs and it is not very clear.

What i don't understand:

- How to make it so that it notifies you in a webhook form (their link for doing this is invalid now)
- What is the form of the webhook (well i know how the simulator event looks like but i want to extract email of buyer)

Here is their API reference: https://shoppy.dev/#/webhooks

So i tried to add a webhook url to my product but there is no way for me to test without buying my own product so i don't know if it worked. I also tried the webhook simulator but i did not find any way to get the email. The only thing i could find on the email was: {enabled: false}.